# Строка подключения в App.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, config

Эх, горе программист, создал подключение к базе и указал хранить строку подключения в app.config
Как теперь избавиться от этого, чтобы имя пользователя и пароль от sql сервера не лежал открытым текстом там?

Comment: Не хранить строку подключения в `app.config`?

Comment: И да, эта гениальная мысль приходила мне. Вопрос в том, как ее оттуда извлечь и поместить в код, чтоб само приложение оставалось рабочим?

Comment: Если SQL сервер это MS SQL Server, то можно использовать интегрированную безопасность

Comment: Там вроде как-то можно хэшик пароля записывать.
Тут вот вроде бы решили эту проблему: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522879/encrypt-password-in-app-config

Comment: @IsM:

1. А где эта строка в `app.config`? Откройте файл в текстовом редакторе и посмотрите. (Только не пишите её на сайте, а то кто-нибудь вас взломает.)
2. Найдите, где в коде используется эта настройка (что-нибудь наподобие `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, или поищите то место, где создаётся подключение), и использование строки из `app.config` на вашу собственную строку.

Comment: @VladD
Не могу в коде найти место, где он это делает. Нет ни одного места, где используется ConnectionString

Comment: @IsM значит плохо ищете - чудес не бывает. Где-то да используется. Пройдитесь отладчиком

Comment: @IsM: ну поищите место, где создаётся подключение.

Comment: У сгенерированного класса есть свойство. Стратегия создания кода: нет/по умолчанию. В данный момент стоит Нет. При выборе по-умолчанию, генерируется код, в котором есть использование строки подключения, но тогда он не компилируется. Еще меня стала преследовать ошибка при манипуляции с дизайнером EntityFramework'a
Извлечь Не удалось найти элемент MyEntities.edmx в рабочей области или у вас нет разрешения на доступ к ней. Возможно это стало происходить после смены версии среды исполнения на 4.0 с 4.5.